# Results from for loop to dataframe, then to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of schools and their offered classes. I also have a list of unique classes, in which only some are offered at various schools, while some are not. I created a loop that outputs the missing classes for each school paired with the name of the school, however I am unable to output the entire results from the for loop to csv.

I am already able to write the classes for a single school to csv, however I am not able to write the entire results of the for loop that includes all the schools to csv.

I know I need to insert the results from the for loop into a dataframe. The next step would be iterating through the dataframe and sending the results line by line to csv, but I first need to get the results from the for loop into a dataframe.

## Read in dataframes

```
schools = {'School': ['School A', 'School A', 'School A', 'School B', 'School B', 'School B', 'School C','School C', 'School D'], 'Class': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'Physics']}
dfSchool = pd.DataFrame(data=schools)
dfSchool


classes = {'Class': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'History', 'Physics']}
dfClasses = pd.DataFrame(data=classes)
dfClasses
```

## For loop

```
grouped = dfSchool.groupby('School')

for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(dfClasses[~(dfClasses.Class.isin(group["Class"]))])
```

## Put results from for loop into data frame (this code doesn't work)

```
listFinal = []
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(dfClasses[~(dfClasses.Class.isin(group["Class"]))])
    listFinal.append(name)
    listFinal.append(dfClasses[~(dfClasses.Class.isin(group["Class"]))])

dfOutput = pd.DataFrame(listFinal)
dfOutput.to_csv('SchoolClasses.csv', index=True)
```

Actual Results:
Console includes the below output, but when written to csv, I only get school A in the file. I want the entire output below (all schools) written to the csv file.

```
School A
     Class
3  History
4  Physics
School B
     Class
3  History
4  Physics
School C
     Class
2  English
3  History
4  Physics
School D
       Class
0       Math
1  Chemistry
2    English
3    History
```

Desired Results:
The above output, but in a single csv file. Bonus points if you can put the school name in every single row of its respective classes, instead of just having the school name as a header.

When trying to put the results from the for loop into a dataframe, I get:

```
listFinal

['School A',      Class
 3  History
 4  Physics, 'School B',      Class
 3  History
 4  Physics, 'School C',      Class
 2  English
 3  History
 4  Physics, 'School D',        Class
 0       Math
 1  Chemistry
 2    English
 3    History]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a direct answer to the question *how to output what has been printed to a csv file*. So I keep your algorithm and only slightly change the content of the `listFinal` list:

```
listFinal = []
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(dfClasses[~(dfClasses.Class.isin(group["Class"]))])
    # add a new column with the class name to the dataframe appended to the list
    listFinal.append(dfClasses[~(dfClasses.Class.isin(group["Class"]))]
                     .assign(School=name))
```

We can then easily output everything to a csv file with a simple pd.concat:

```
dfOutput = pd.concat(listFinal)
dfOutput.to_csv('SchoolClasses.csv', index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the schools dataframe:

```
schools = {
    "School": [
        "School A",
        "School A",
        "School A",
        "School B",
        "School B",
        "School B",
        "School C",
        "School C",
        "School D",
    ],
    "Class": [
        "Math",
        "Chemistry",
        "English",
        "Math",
        "Chemistry",
        "English",
        "Math",
        "Chemistry",
        "Physics",
    ],
}
dfSchool = pd.DataFrame(data=schools)
print(dfSchool)

     School      Class
0  School A       Math
1  School A  Chemistry
2  School A    English
3  School B       Math
4  School B  Chemistry
5  School B    English
6  School C       Math
7  School C  Chemistry
8  School D    Physics
```

Create a dataframe that would show what it would look like if all schools had all the classes. Call this df_tot

```
s = ['School A'] * len(c) + ['School B']* len(c) + ['School C']* len(c) + ['School D']* len(c)
c = ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'History', 'Physics']

df_tot = pd.DataFrame([s, c*4], index=['School','Class']).T

print(df_tot)

     School      Class
0   School A       Math
1   School A  Chemistry
2   School A    English
3   School A    History
4   School A    Physics
5   School B       Math
6   School B  Chemistry
7   School B    English
8   School B    History
9   School B    Physics
10  School C       Math
11  School C  Chemistry
12  School C    English
13  School C    History
14  School C    Physics
15  School D       Math
16  School D  Chemistry
17  School D    English
18  School D    History
19  School D    Physics
```

Do an outer merge and select indicator to True, then filter for _merge == left_only.

```
df_tot = df_tot[df_tot.merge(dfSchool, how='outer', indicator=True)['_merge'] == 'left_only'])

print(df_tot)

      School      Class
3   School A    History
4   School A    Physics
8   School B    History
9   School B    Physics
12  School C    English
13  School C    History
14  School C    Physics
15  School D       Math
16  School D  Chemistry
17  School D    English
18  School D    History
```

Save to csv...

```
df_tot.to_csv('anyfile.csv')
```

**Alternative answer to Dataframe**

I'm wondering if using dictionaries and json isn't just easier?

```
School = [
    "School A",
    "School A",
    "School A",
    "School B",
    "School B",
    "School B",
    "School C",
    "School C",
    "School D",
]

Class = [
    "Math",
    "Chemistry",
    "English",
    "Math",
    "Chemistry",
    "English",
    "Math",
    "Chemistry",
    "Physics",
]
```

Make a list of existing classes in schools.

```
A = list(zip(School, Class))

for item in A:
    print(item)

('School A', 'Math')
('School A', 'Chemistry')
('School A', 'English')
('School B', 'Math')
('School B', 'Chemistry')
('School B', 'English')
('School C', 'Math')
('School C', 'Chemistry')
('School D', 'Physics')
```

Put this into a dcitionary:

```
d1 = {}
for item in A:
    d1.setdefault(item[0], []).append(item[1])

print(d1)

{'School A': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English'],
 'School B': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English'],
 'School C': ['Math', 'Chemistry'],
 'School D': ['Physics']}
```

Build a new dictionary out of items not in d1:

```
d2 = {}
for s in set(School):  
    for c in set(Class):
        if c in d1[s]:
            continue
        else:
            d2.setdefault(s,[]).append(c)


print(d2)

{'School C': ['Physics', 'English'],
 'School A': ['Physics'],
 'School B': ['Physics'],
 'School D': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English']}
```

Then I would consider using json file:

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(d2, fp)
```

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. While this works in this scenario, I am trying to apply this logic to a much larger data set, that includes over 100 "school" objects and around 1,000 "class" objects. Thus, I need to incorporate loops into the problem to avoid manually typing out large amounts of code. Is there any other way you know how to convert the results from the below for loop into a dataframe then to a csv?                
```grouped = dfSchool.groupby('School')

for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(dfClasses[~(dfClasses.Class.isin(group["Class"]))])```

Answer (score 1):

The following code aggregates all missing classes into one set for each school.

```
schools = {'School': ['School A', 'School A', 'School A', 'School B', 'School B', 'School B', 'School C','School C', 'School D'], 'Class': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'Physics']}
dfSchool = pd.DataFrame(schools)

classes = {'Class': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'History', 'Physics']}

set_classes = set(classes["Class"])
df = dfSchool.groupby('School').agg(lambda c: set_classes.difference(c))
df.name = "MissingClasses"
df.to_csv("SchoolClasses.csv")
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for answering, this definitely works, however it wasn't the exact output format I was looking for. But thanks a lot I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.apply`:

```
import pandas as pd


schools = {'School': ['School A', 'School A', 'School A', 
                      'School B', 'School B', 'School B',
                      'School C', 'School C', 'School D'],
           'Class': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English',
                     'Math', 'Chemistry', 'English',
                     'Math', 'Chemistry', 'Physics']
           }

classes = {'Class': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'History', 'Physics']}

df_school = pd.DataFrame(data=schools)
df_classes = pd.DataFrame(data=classes)

missing = (df_school.groupby('School')
                    .apply(lambda group: df_classes[~(df_classes["Class"].isin(group["Class"]))])
                    .droplevel(-1)
                    )
missing.to_csv("missing_classes.csv")
```

Result:

```
>>> missing
              Class
School             
School A    History
School A    Physics
School B    History
School B    Physics
School C    English
School C    History
School C    Physics
School D       Math
School D  Chemistry
School D    English
School D    History
```

### missing_classes.csv

> School,Class
>   School A,History
>   School A,Physics
>   School B,History
>   School B,Physics
>   School C,English
>   School C,History
>   School C,Physics
>   School D,Math
>   School D,Chemistry
>   School D,English
>   School D,History